# remove return to line from scraped website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

i'm trying to scrape a website this is the target div look like this

```
                              <div class="entry-footer">
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Mots-clefs :</strong>
                                    A Gray State 4,
                                    A Gray State 3,
                                    A Gray State 2,                                     
                                </p>
                            </div>`
```

i'm trying to scrape the text using this method

```
myurl = 'http://agb.xyz'
uclient = uReq(myurl)
page_html =uclient.read()
uclient.close()
pag_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
tags = pag_soup.find_all("div",{"class":"entry-footer"})
finaltags = tags[0].text.replace('/n',' ')
print(finaltags)`
```

the resulat  i got 
! https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbWlh.jpg
but what i want is to text look like this

> Mots-clefs : A Gray State 4, A Gray State 3, A Gray State 2,

i want to replace retur to line with space

Comment: isn't it `\n` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look what happens when you print the actual representation of your output string:

```
>>> repr(tags[0].text)
'\n\nMots-clefs :\n    A Gray State 4,\n    A Gray State 3,\n    A Gray State 2,                                     \n  \n'
```

You have a few issues here, both newline characters (which are `\n`, and not `/n`), as well as undesired continuous whitespace.  However, you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace both of these with single spaces, to achieve your desired result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<div class="entry-footer">
  <p>
    <strong>Mots-clefs :</strong>
    A Gray State 4,
    A Gray State 3,
    A Gray State 2,                                     
  </p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"entry-footer"})[0].text
print(re.sub(r'(\s+|\n)', ' ', tags))
```

Output:

```
Mots-clefs : A Gray State 4, A Gray State 3, A Gray State 2,
```

Comment: thk a lot for ur help

Answer (score 1):

Or without regex:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
 <div class="entry-footer">
    <p>
        <strong>Mots-clefs :</strong>
        A Gray State 4,
        A Gray State 3,
        A Gray State 2,                                     
    </p>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".entry-footer p strong"):
    title = items.text
    data = ' '.join([' '.join(item.split()) for item in items.next_siblings])
    print(title,data)
```

Output:

```
Mots-clefs : A Gray State 4, A Gray State 3, A Gray State 2,
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a line break, you can try using `\n` **not** `/n`, i.e.:

## Linux, macOS

```
tags[0].text.replace('\n',' ')
```

## Windows

```
tags[0].text.replace('\r\n',' ')
```

Or use [`strip()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm):

```
tags[0].text.strip()
```

---

## Newline

Frequently called **line ending**, **end of line** (**EOL**), **line feed**, or **line break**, is a *[control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)* in a *[character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)* specification, like e.g. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). It is used to signify the end of a [line of text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(text_file)) and the start of a new one. Text editors set this special character when pressing the [Enter key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key).

---

[Representations in different character encoding specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations_in_different_character_encoding_specifications)

1. [Multics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics), [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) and [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) systems ([Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD), [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIX_operating_system), [Xenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenix), etc.), [BeOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeOS), [Amiga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga), [RISC OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC_OS), and others[[1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#cite_note-1)

   **- Escape sequence**: `\n`
2. [Atari TOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_TOS), [Microsoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) ([MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS), [PC DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_DOS), etc.), [DEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Equipment_Corporation) [TOPS-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOPS-10), [RT-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RT-11), [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M), [MP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP/M), [OS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2), [Symbian OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian_OS), [Palm OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_OS), [Amstrad CPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amstrad_CPC), and most other early non-Unix and non-IBM operating systems

   **-  Escape sequence** : `\r\n`

---

## Unicode

The [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) standard defines a number of characters that conforming applications should recognize as line terminators:

`LF`:  Line Feed, `U+000A`
`VT`:  [Vertical Tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_Tab), `U+000B`
`FF`:  [Form Feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_Feed), `U+000C`
`CR`:  [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), `U+000D`
`CR+LF`: `CR` (`U+000D`) followed by `LF` (`U+000A`)
`NEL`:  Next Line, `U+0085`
`LS`:  Line Separator, `U+2028`
`PS`:  Paragraph Separator, `U+2029`

Comment: you said you can try using \n not /n and i did not work and about the info that u grab from wiik it's now helpful what i need is someone to help modifying the code not grabing some info from wiki this is not quora and again thk fro ur effort

Comment: Don't use `string` as a variable name, as it overrides a python module.

Comment: `string` isn't a type in python, `str` is the type.  If you are referring to the general function it's `str.replace`